# viewWillLayoutSubviews is getting called way too much

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, uikit

In my `viewController.view`, I have some work done in `viewWillLayoutSubviews` that organizes which subviews are visible, which to bring to the front, which to hide, etc, if the orientation changes.

But I have buttons on my view that somehow cause `viewWillLayoutSubviews` to get called every time they are pressed. Why would this be? According to the Apple docs, `viewWillLayoutSubviews` is only called if your view's bounds change.

The result is that my views are getting re-arranged just from pressing a button, but I'm not rotating the device at all nor am I manipulating view.bounds or view.frame in any way.

Comment: Can you tell what operation you are performing at button press??

Comment: Yes, the button press creates and adds a subview to the view.

Comment: Definitely, It is because of adding subview on pressing button.

Comment: That makes sense, because of adding a subview, it tries again to layout subviews.

Comment: You better do one thing andrews take a bool and set it TRUE on button press and check it on layoutSubviews and operate whether it is true or false. You get it what i am trying to do.

Comment: i know what you mean and I had a similar idea; make your comment an answer so i can accept it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You better do one thing andrews take a bool and set it TRUE on button press and check it on layoutSubviews and operate whether it is true or false. You get it what i am trying to do.

Comment: i accept also based on comments you left to my question above

Comment: so finally what solution are you using for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Its weird , I wrote a demo just 2 methods , one for button's action and one is `- (void)viewWillLayoutSubviews`, when I pressed the button, `- (void)viewWillLayoutSubviews` is not called.Maybe some mistake in your code?

Comment: note the comments to my question, it appears as though the culprit has been found